# jee:remote-slsb use custom factory

Tags: spring, ejb

i have this definition for calling an EJB

```
<util:properties id="ejbJndiConfig" location="file:/path/to/ejb-jndi-config.properties" />

<jee:remote-slsb id="myEjbService"
    jndi-name="myEjbName"
    business-interface="foo.bar.MyBusinessInterface"
    cache-home="false"
    lookup-home-on-startup="false"
    refresh-home-on-connect-failure="true"
    environment-ref="ejbJndiConfig"
    expose-access-context="true">
</jee:remote-slsb>
```

All is working great and an instance of:

`org.springframework.ejb.access.SimpleRemoteStatelessSessionProxyFactoryBean` is created to call the EJB method. But what about if i want to change this default behaviour and change the used class?

With old style spring we can do something like this:

```
<bean id="service" class="org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiProxyFactoryBean">
<property name="remoteInvocationFactory" ref="invocationFactory"/>
....
</bean>

<bean id="invocationFactory" class="src.rmi.CustomRemoteInvocationFactory"/>
```

is possible with new definition style?

Comment: Why are you comparing EJB and RMI? Those are 2 different (well one uses the other when needed) things.

Comment: RMI is the technology used to call an EJB method or not?

Comment: That depends if it is local or not. But from your configuration point-of-view what you configure are 2 completely different things. So not sure how those are related.